# Evaluation order in initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, aggregate-initialization

In the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct I {
    int i;
    I(){i=2;}
    I(int _i){i=_i;}
};
int a[3] = {a[2] = 1};
int aa[3][3] = {aa[2][2] = 1};
I A[3] = {A[2].i = 1};
I AA[3][3] = {AA[2][2].i = 1};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int b : a) std::cout << b << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto &bb : aa) for (auto &b : bb) std::cout << b << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto &B : A) std::cout << B.i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto &BB : AA) for (auto &B : BB) std::cout << B.i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 2 2 
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

from  http://ideone.com/1ueWdK with clang3.7

but the result is :

```
0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 2 2 
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

on http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang also with clang 3.7.

On my own ubuntu, gcc 6.2 givs an internal compiler error on the construct `int aa[3][3] = {aa[2][2] = 1}`.

I'm assuming this is undefined behavior, but cannot find a definitive statement in the standard.

The question is:

Whether the evaluation order of the side effects on the assignment in the initializer list (e.g. `a[2] = 1`) and initialization of the actual element of the array (e.g. `a[2]`) defined in the standard?

It is explicitly stated as defined or undefined? Or does it become undefined just because it is not explicitly defined?

Or does the construct has defined or undefined behavior due to other reason aside from the evaluation order?

Comment: My eyes are bleeding... If this ain't an upvote, I have no idea what would be...

Comment: [Doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/ZT1N3K).  Also internal compiler errors can result if your code is so messed up that the compiler's parser blows up.

Comment: compiles in gcc 4.9 and clang ... gcc 5+ has a bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with the simplest case:

> ```
> I A[3] = {A[2].i = 1};
> I AA[3][3] = {AA[2][2].i = 1};
> ```

Both of these are UB, due to a violation of [basic.life]. You are accessing the value of an object before its lifetime has begun. `I` does not have a trivial default constructor, and therefore cannot be vacuously initialized. Therefore, the object's lifetime only begins once a constructor has completed. The elements of the `A` array have not yet been constructed when you are accessing elements of that array.

Therefore, you are invoking UB by accessing a not-yet-constructed object.

Now, the other two cases are more complex:

> ```
> int a[3] = {a[2] = 1};
> int aa[3][3] = {aa[2][2] = 1};
> ```

See, `int` permits "vacuous initialization", as defined by [basic.life]/1. Storage for `a` and `aa` has been acquired. Therefore, `int a[3]` is a valid array of `int` objects, even though aggregate initialization has not yet begun. So accessing the object and even setting its state is not UB.

The order of operations here is fixed. Even pre-C++17, the initialization of the elements of the initializer list is sequenced before the aggregate initialization is invoked, as stated in [dcl.init.list]/4. Elements in the aggregate which are not listed in the initialization list here will be filled in as if by `typename{}` constructs. `int{}` means to value-initialize an `int`, which results in 0.

So even though you set `a[2]` and `aa[2][2]`, they should immediately be overwritten via aggregate initialization.

Therefore, *all of these compilers are wrong*. The answer should be:

> ```
> 1 0 0 
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

Now granted, this is all very stupid and you shouldn't do it. But from a pure language perspective, this is well-defined behavior.

Comment: A small nitpick: there's a special provision for using objects before their lifetime started [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6), which leads to [this clause](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1) saying that you can access the object members as soon as the object's constructor started - not finished.